# C++ raytracer bug

Tags: c++, graphics, raytracing

I've written a raytracer in C++. This is the snippet for calculating the diffuse component:

```
//diffuse component
    color diffuse(0, 0, 0);
    if (intrs.mat.diffuseness > 0)
    {
        for (auto &light : lights)
        {
            //define ray from hit object to light
            ray light_dir(intrs.point, (light->point - intrs.point).normalize());
            double nl = light_dir.direction*intrs.normal; //dot product
            double diminish_coeff = 1.0;
            double dist = intrs.point.sqrDistance(light->point);
            //check whether it reaches the light
            if (nl > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < (int)shapes.size(); ++i)
                {
                    shape::intersection temp_intrs(shapes[i]->intersect(light_dir, shapes[i]->interpolate_normals));
                    if (temp_intrs.valid && temp_intrs.point.sqrDistance(intrs.point) < dist)
                    {
                        diminish_coeff *= shadow_darkness;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            diffuse += intrs.mat.diffuseness * intrs.mat.col * light->light_color * light->light_intensity * nl*diminish_coeff;
        }
    }
```

Of course, I can't post the entire code, but I think it should be clear what I'm doing here - `intrs` is the current intersection of a ray and object and `shapes` is a vector of all objects in the scene.

Colors are represented as RGB in the (0,1) range. Addition and multiplication of colors are simple memberwise addition and multiplication. Only when the raytracing is over, and I want to write into the image file, I multiply my colors by 255 and clamp to 255 if a component is larger than that.

Currently, there is one point light in the scene and it's white: color(1,1,1), intensity = 1.0.

This is my rendered image:
[image]

So, this is not right - the cupboard on the left is supposed to be green, and the box is supposed to be red.

Is there something obviously wrong with my implementation? I can't seem to figure it out. I'll post some more code if necessary.

Comment: I might say something wrong, be should'nt `nl` be the dot product ?

Comment: @rak007 It is the dot product. :) I'll note that in my question.

Comment: On the same note, could you add some more explanation on how your `color`class implements the `+=` overload ?

Comment: 1. How many lights are in the scene? 2. Are all factors in the `diffuse +=` expression `<= 1`.?

Comment: @rak007 I just add to each component separately, so (100,20,20)+(10,10,0)=(110,30,20) and then clamp it (set to 255 if it's larger than that) later, when the rendering is over.

Comment: @Angew One light, completely white. And yes, they are.

Comment: And how do your *colour* vectors implement `*`? You seem to be using the range `0-255`, so what is the result of `color(10, 10, 10) * color(100, 100, 100)`?

Comment: @Angew Just memberwise multiplication, and components will later be clamped to 255

Comment: @Eutherpy Please [edit] that into the question, it's crucial info.

Comment: my bet is the clamping is the problem ... if you got `(260,260,1000)` and clamp to `(255,255,255)` then you lose colors ... instead you should do `(r,g,b)*=255/max(r,g,b)` or use less bright lights or use HDR

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your `diffuse +=` line should be *inside* the `if (nl > 0)` condition, not outside it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. For some reason, my `intrs.normal` vector wasn't normalized. Thank you everyone for your help.